# Google earth plugin z-index issue in chrome/windows

Tags: css, google-earth-plugin

I've been working on a project which uses google earth. The layout is pretty simple. I have full screen google earth object and a div. I use z-index to stack each other. It works well in chrome/mac, however, z-index doesn't work in chrome/windows.

Comment: Do you have an example we can see? Also do you have `position:relative` or `position:absolute` on the element with the `z-index` applied?

Comment: GE has a fixed position and div has relative one.

Comment: Hard to know what is going on without looking at code, can you make a fiddle? http://jsfiddle.net/ - do any of the parent elements have a `z-index`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a well known issue. The only known work around is to use iframe shims. Here is an example

http://earth-api-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/demos/customcontrols/index.html